# Send JSON object to Struts 2 action by using strut2 jquery plugin tags

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, struts2, struts2-jquery

We can send JSON to Struts2 actions by `json` interceptor. There is good sample at http://tech.learnerandtutor.com/send-json-object-to-struts-2-action-by-jquery-ajax/.

The `json` interceptor requires that the requests `content type` be `application/json` or `application/json-rpc` this can be set when we directly use Ajax like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "writeJSON.action",
    data: data1,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
```

But we are using struts 2 jquery plugin tags (`sj:a` and `sj:submit` ...) which manage ajax calls for us.

Is there any way that we can set the `contentType` with these tags.

I did not find tag properties for this.

If it is not implemented is there any other way to set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `Content-type: application/json` header to xhr object that is used by the `$.ajax()`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "writeJSON.action",
    data: data1,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
```

The plugin is using `$.ajaxSubmit()`, this kind of submission should be eliminated because it doesn't work with json data.

Comment: Dear @RomanC, thanks, But I get the `TypeError: xhr is undefined` we are using struts 2 jquery plugin version `3.7.1` . The `event.originalEvent` has `form`, `formData`, and `options` properties.

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi Yes, it's undefined, the topic is published before this object is created.

Comment: Just a note, the `xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", 'application/json');` works if you use it in `ajaxSend` like this `$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, settings) {if(youCondition) xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", 'application/json'); });` There you have the `xhr` and can hack it. Anyway, I think the pure `$.ajax` seems more logical in this case

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi You can continue hacking the plugin, becoz it doesn't work with dynamic attributes and you can't pass the content type that you need it in either api.